# How to implement boost MPL FOLD in C++11 only using parameter pack ?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, variadic-templates, boost-mpl

boost mpl has more common algo - [fold](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/fold.html) . This algo is basic for many other algorithms.

```
template< typename Seq, typename State, typename Op> struct fold { ... }
//Here Seq is <T0,T1,...,Tn> any sequence.
// result of fold is  op<  op < ...< op<State,T0>::type, T1>::type > ... >, Tn>::type
```

for more information read [link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/fold.html).

`Fold` in c++11 with variadic templates may redefined following:

```
 template< typename state, typename op, typename ...elements> struct fold;
```

How to implement it is not problem, but  HOW TO IMPLEMENT IT using only parameter
packing is difficult or may unsolveable problem.

**Q: Can it to implement only using parameter packing??**

I want something like

```
template< typename OP, typename State, typename ...T>
struct fold
{
     // only for illustration
     typedef  apply< apply<....<apply<Op,State,T>>...>::type type; 
};
```

Comment: How to do X using technique Y is not a "practical" problem.  How to do it without linear template instantiation depth is a "practical" problem that might be what you want answered.  Is that what you want answered?  Or is there an actual practical "I need a parameter pack based implmenetation" I'm missing?

Comment: It's practical actual, because parameter pack based implementation very fast compiled than linear implementation. I'm work on a project, which used boost msm library, and project compiled about one hour. Sometimes ccache may helpes, but I lost a many time compiling.

Comment: speed of compiling is a practical problem: thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: For compiling project need about an hour time and more than 6 Gb RAM. For your mind,  this is not practical problem !!! 
I'll have to compile 4-5 times a day. My 30-40% working time will be spent on compiling only.

Comment: I said it was a practical problem in my previous comment?  I am now confused.

Comment: Oh,sorry. I thought you said the figurative expression. Because many times I heard it. Many programmers which I know they think that the compile time is not practical problem, the main thing is runtime-speed.

and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a stab at a logarithmic template recursion depth `fold` implementation.

```
#include <cstddef>

template<typename... Ts> struct types {};
template<typename T, typename U>
struct concat;
template<typename... Ts, typename... Us>
struct concat< types<Ts...>, types<Us...> > {
  typedef types<Ts..., Us...> result;
};
template<typename Ts, typename Us>
using Concat = typename concat<Ts, Us>::result;

template<std::size_t n, typename Ts>
struct split;
template<std::size_t n, typename... Ts>
struct split<n, types<Ts...>> {
private:
  typedef split<n/2, types<Ts...>> one;
  typedef split<n-n/2, typename one::right> two;
public:
  typedef Concat< typename one::left, typename two::left > left;
  typedef typename two::right right;
};
template<typename... Ts>
struct split<0, types<Ts...>> {
  typedef types<> left;
  typedef types<Ts...> right;
};
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct split<1, types<T, Ts...>> {
  typedef types<T> left;
  typedef types<Ts...> right;
};
template<template<typename, typename>class OP, typename State, typename Ts>
struct fold_helper;
template<template<typename, typename>class OP, typename State, typename... Ts>
struct fold_helper<OP, State, types<Ts...>> {
private:
  typedef split<sizeof...(Ts)/2, types<Ts...>> parts;
  typedef typename parts::left left;
  typedef typename parts::right right;
  typedef typename fold_helper<OP, State, left>::result left_result;
public:
  typedef typename fold_helper<OP, left_result, right>::result result;
};
template<template<typename, typename>class OP, typename State>
struct fold_helper<OP, State, types<>> {
  typedef State result;
};
template<template<typename, typename>class OP, typename State, typename T>
struct fold_helper<OP, State, types<T>> {
  typedef typename OP<State,T>::type result;
};
template<template<typename, typename>class OP, typename State, typename... Ts>
struct fold {
  typedef typename fold_helper<OP, State, types<Ts...>>::result type;
};
template<template<typename, typename>class OP, typename State, typename... Ts>
using Fold = typename fold<OP, State, Ts...>::type;

template<typename left, typename right>
struct op_test {
  typedef int type;
};

int main() {
  Fold< op_test, double, int, char, char*, int* > foo = 8;
}
```

here I first take the linear list, and break it into two half-length lists using the `split` metafunction.

Once I have two halves, I `fold` over the first half, then take the result of that and `fold` over the second half.

While O(N) work is done, you are only O(lg(N)) deep at any point.

I don't see a theoretical reason why we cannot pull off O(lg(lg(N)) depth, but neither do I see the point: with a ~1000 max depth, you'd have to have dozens of nested `fold`s on type lists 100s long to run out of template stack space: in my experience the compiler blows up long before the logarithmic depth limit is reached.

And now it compiles: http://ideone.com/CdKAAT

`split` is a generally useful way of dealing with long lists without recursing once per element.  `fold` and `fold_helper` are pretty obvious once you have the logarithmic `split`.

Comment: I have test it with 1000 arguments with clang 3.3. Compiled at 3.5 s.
This is not required deep recursion, but this is compiled about 3x time slow than linear implementation of `fold`.

Comment: @khurshid try 10000 - if the compiler has a template recursion limit, this should hit it slower than linear.  It will, as you note, take longer to compile at most practical sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Why the restriction on only parameter packing?

Like many parameter pack solutions, you're likely going to have to delve into either some sort of overloading or partial specialization. Given that you're writing a template metafunction, I would go with partial specialization.

The below handles the case with 0 elements by returning state, and we use that position in the template to accumulate the result.  The specialization handles the 1+ case, by combining the first element with the state, and recursively calling the template metafunction.

```
template< typename OP, typename State, typename ...T>
struct fold
{
    typedef State type;
};

template<typename OP, typename State, typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct fold< OP, State, Head, Tail...>
{
   typedef typename fold<OP, typename OP::template apply<State,Head>::type, Tail...>::type type;
};
```

http://ideone.com/DDCCbB